# How to hide login button on revolution slider once the user loggedin

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a wordpress website in which i have put a login button on the revolution slider. I want the login button hides when the user loggedin to wordpress website. I see there is option in menus to show for loggedin or loggedout users but i don't know how to hide login on revolution slider when the user loggedin

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to check if the user is logged in or not. Then, implement your logic to hide the login button from revolution slider. 
[Check if user is logged in using JQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/check-if-user-is-logged-in-using-jquery)

Your jQuery would look something like this:

```
$('.rev-slider-login-button').hide();
```